# loading json through javascript/D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to load a json file and then do some processing on it, however for some of the values that I load and display in the console I get ***Nans***.

I pasted the code below and attached console output and I cannot figure out why I am getting a difference in the results/output on console. Any help is much appreciated

File Contents:

```
[
   {"sn": 12312312, "sc":0 , "dn": 42131221, "dc":1 }
 , {"sn": 42131221, "sc":1 , "dn": 21422111, "dc":2 }
]
```

Code:

```
<script src="js/d3-3-5-5.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var margin = {top: 16, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0}
,width = 950 - margin.left - margin.right
,height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");  

var dataParser = function(d) {
    var r= {
        act: Number(d.sc),
        id: Number(d.sn),
        x: parseFloat(d.sc) + Math.random(),
        y: parseFloat(d.sc) + Math.random(),
        radius: 5
    };
    return r

   }

var nodes = [];
var dataset;
d3.json("data/event.json", function(error, data) {    
dataset=data;
dataset.forEach(function(d) {
    new_r = dataParser(d);
    console.log(new_r);
    nodes.push(new_r);
    console.log(nodes);
 });   
});


// Force-directed layout
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .size([width, height])
    .gravity(0)
    .charge(0)
    .friction(.91)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();



// Draw circle for each node.

var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
    .attr("class", "node")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.act); });  

function tick(e) {
   circle
     .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.act); })
}

function color(activity) {

var colorByActivity = {
    "0": "#e0d400",
    "1": "#1c8af9",
    "2": "#51BC05",
    "3": "#FF7F00",
    "4": "#DB32A4",
    "5": "#00CDF8",
    "6": "#E63B60",
    "7": "#8E5649",
    "8": "#68c99e",
    "9": "#a477c8",
    "10": "#5C76EC",
    "11": "#E773C3",
    "12": "#799fd2",
    "13": "#038a6c",
    "14": "#cc87fa",
    "15": "#ee8e76",
    "16": "#bbbbbb",
  }

return colorByActivity[activity];

}

</script>
```

[image: Console Output]

The weird thing is when I expand the json object on console even though it shows correct values for x and y the expanded object shows Nan and I can wrap my head around this.

[image]

I am using the developer tools in chrome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce your [problem here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yejkR05OtHGGDqRs1yYo?p=preview).  Also, there's more code to this you aren't sharing with us.  For instance, what's creating the `px` and `py` values?

Comment: Also, when you print to the console and expand, you are seeing what the values are *currently* in memory.  Not what they were when you printed it.

Comment: Thank you Mark for your reply, I have pasted the entire code that I am working with. I cant see the circles I am trying to draw dynamically  and the console suggests x and y values are Nan. Is there any other way to see/preserve the values of x and y for debugging. Sorry it might be a stupid question, I've just started with js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I close this question, as it's a duplicate many times over but I'll answer adding a little d3 help along the way.

First, your big problem, `d3.json` is an async operation.  When it completes, it fires a callback function (your second argument to it).  The code you have below `d3.json` that builds your force layour is actually executing **before** the `d3.json` finishes.  It needs to execute in the callback.

Second, couple svg/d3 things:

1. Your circles have no radius, they won't appear
2. You don't position your circles in the tick function
3. You don't need all the number conversion and float parsing, it isn't doing anything

---

[Here it is running a bit better](http://plnkr.co/edit/yejkR05OtHGGDqRs1yYo?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips and help :-)